# The welcome message is sent to my server?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have specified the channel ID in my code. When a new member joins my server, the message is sent to the channel where I want it, but when a member of my server joins another server where my bot is located, the welcome message is sent to my server, although the member is already on it and has just joined another server. My question is, how can I fix the bot not sending the welcome message to my server when a member joins another server?

And my second question is, how can I set up that, for example, administrators from other servers can choose where to send the welcome message to their servers?

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x6c5ce7)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Welcome, {member.name}#{member.discriminator}!\n", value=f":white_small_square: Check the <#848929002281631744> channel and read the rules!\n"
                                                                                                f":white_small_square: Then look in the <#848929105109057567> channel and follow the instructions!\n\n"
                                                                                                f"Have fun on our Server!", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"New Member: {member.name}#{member.discriminator}", icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    await client.get_channel(865655108230447175).send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: IDs are unique, you should do it by name instead.

Comment: If you want other server owner(s) to be able to choose where the message is sent you have to use a database like mysql or a simple JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it would be to check whether the guild the member is joining is your guild. The best and most accurate way to do this would be via id.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # check if the guild the member is joining is equal to your guild's id 
    if member.guild.id != YOUR GUILD ID:
        return
    # if it's the same guild id, it continues
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x6c5ce7)
    # etc, other code
```

If you want to use it in multiple of your own servers, you could consider using a json, which may store the guild ids as well as the channel ids, and use a similar concept as seen in the code above.